# Error in Rake Task in Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins, rakefile

When I'm trying to install the plugins by Rake command I'm getting the below error can any one help?

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate:RAILS_ENV=production

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'redmine:plugins:migrate:RAILS_ENV'
```

Note that im using 2.2.0 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RAILS_ENV=production` part should be prepended to your command.

Try:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate
```